# Slow Excel Shutdown When WPF Called from Add-In

Tags: wpf, vb.net, excel, add-in

I have an Excel add-in with a button on it that calls a WPF application on a new thread. When I close Excel not having opened my WPF application or after opening it and then closing it again, Excel closes immediately, however, whenever I open the application and then close Excel, Excel takes 5-10 seconds to close. I've only come across these solutions, neither of which has helped:

- [VSTO Runtime Update to Address Slow Shutdown...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2014/04/10/vsto-runtime-update-to-address-slow-shutdown-and-unknown-publisher-for-sha256-certificates.aspx)
- [This one sort of asks the question, but the asker's issue ends up being different.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b6872f97-7776-40ca-98dd-27a6065f7b3f/word-and-excel-2010-slow-to-quit-upon-opening-a-wpf-window-in-addin?forum=vsto)

I'm running VS 2010 and Excel 2010, so there shouldn't be an interoperability problem.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thread Code:

```
Private qbdThread As Thread = Nothing
Private frmQBD As QBDApplication.MainWindow

qbdThread = New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf RunQBD))
qbdThread.SetApartmentState(Threading.ApartmentState.STA)
qbdThread.Start(TabletType)
AddHandler QBDApplication.MainWindow.QBDClose, AddressOf QBDThreadClose

Private Sub RunQBD(Optional tabletQBDSelected As String = Nothing)
...

frmQBD = New QBDApplication.MainWindow(contacts, saveLocation, tabletQBDLocal)
frmQBD.Show()
frmQBD.Activate()
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
End Sub
```

This code runs when the app is closed by the user on the new thread:

```
Me.Close()
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown()
```

An event is then raised on the main thread (ThisAddin.vb) with this code:

```
Private Sub QBDThreadClose()
    qbdThread = Nothing
    frmQBD = Nothing
End Sub
```

One other thing to note is that when frmQBD is not created as a class variable, and instead dimensioned in the "RunQBD" sub, this issue does not occur. This would solve my problem, but then I wouldn't be able to access something like frmQBD.Activate() on the main thread, which I need to be able to do.

**EDIT: Code has been updated**

Comment: Have you tried installing the update mentioned in the first link to check whether that resolves the problem?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I mentioned it. Should have been clearer.

Answer (score 5):

We found a solution for this problem.

You have to set an [AppSwith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appcontext.setswitch?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.AppContext.SetSwitch);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.8) in the framework

```
Public Sub EnablePointerSupport()
AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Windows.Input.Stylus.EnablePointerSupport",True)
End Sub
```

You can find more information about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/appcontextswitchoverrides-element) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/mitigation-pointer-based-touch-and-stylus-support).

Comment: You have just helped me to resolve the issue which has been hanging on me in Jira for the last 6 months! Thank you for posting your answer!

Comment: Is there any intuition to why this solves the issue? I have an VSTO add-in with a WPF panel. Depending on the version of Office running the add-in the issue with long closing  time is experienced. It may be my lack of understanding, but it seems a little hacky to solve it by setting the switch?

Answer (score 1):

This Microsoft bug is described at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/783019/word-slow-shutdown-on-windows-8-when-using-wpf-in-application-addin.  It was initially reported in 2013 and supposedly fixed in 2014, but appears to be back now.

We can reproduce this exact problem with Excel and Word 2016 running on Windows 10, but mysteriously not in PowerPoint.  Latest version of VSTO Runtime is installed.  We could not reproduce the problem in Office 2013 running on Windows 8.1.

The workaround is as described at the link above--go to Device Manager > Human Interface Devices and disable "HID-compliant touch screen" (in our testing) or perhaps another one of the "HID-compliant" items.

Comment: Have the same problem with Windows 10 (1903) and a new surface device. Any recomandations?

Comment: Update:  we can now reproduce the problem in Office 2013 running on Windows 8.1.  The problem was observed after installing a recent Office update, but we cannot confirm that the update is responsible for this behavior.  In any case, this problem seems to have only grown in scope since it was reportedly fixed in 2014.